# The product of regular submanifolds is a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Suppose $S_1$ and $S_2$ are regular submanifolds of $M_1$ and $M_2$, respectively. I would like to show that $S_1 \times S_2$ is a regular submanifold of $M_1 \times M_2$.

My attempt: Suppose $p_1 \in S_1$ and $p_2 \in S_2$. Then there exists coordinate map $(U_1, \phi_1)$ containing $p_1$ and another coordinate map $(U_2, \phi_2)$ containing $p_2$. Since a product of manifolds is a manifold, we have that $(p_1, p_2) \in (U_1, U_2)$ and that $(U_1 \times U_2, \phi_1 \times \phi_2)$ is a coordinate map on $M_1 \times M_2$. Since it was assumed that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are regular submanifolds, we have that on $U_1 \cap S$ a finitely many number of the coordinate functions vanish, and likewise for $U_2 \cap S_2$. Hence it follows that on
$$(U_1 \times U_2) \cap (S_1 \times S_2) = (U_1 \cap S_1) \times (U_2 \times S_2)$$
a finitely many number of the coordinate functions also vanish. Since $(p_1, p_2)$ was arbitrary, we are done.

My proof feels a little incomplete. Am I missing anything or is this fine?

Comment: Can you state the definition of regular submanifold that you are using? There are several equivalent definitions.

Comment: @Didier I am using Tu's book which gives the following definition: "A subset $S$ of a manifold $N$ of dimension $n$ is a *regular submanifold* of dimension $k$ if for every $p \in S$ there is a coordinate neighborhood $(U, \phi) = (U, x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ of $p$ in the maximal atlas of $N$ such that $U \cap S$ is defined by the vanishing of $n-k$ of the coordinate functions. By renumbering the coordinates, we may assume that these $n-k$ coordinates are $x^{k+1},\ldots, x^n$".

Comment: Then your proof is OK. If you feel the need to be absolutely complete, maybe you can explicitly state which coordinates vanish to define $S_1\times S_2$

Comment: @Didier Thank you.